# count all rising edge only (not falling edge) values by day stored in log MySQL table

Tags: mysql, logging, statistics

### THE ISSUE

I need to get all defaults per day of a machine which logs are stored in a MySQL table every 5 seconds like this :

| time | def1 | def2 | def3 | def4 | def5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 12:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-09-01 12:00:05 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-09-01 12:00:10 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-09-01 12:00:15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-09-01 12:00:20 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-09-01 12:00:25 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-09-01 12:00:30 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-09-01 12:00:35 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-09-01 12:00:40 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-09-01 12:00:45 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-09-02 12:00:00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-09-02 12:00:05 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-09-02 12:00:10 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-09-02 12:00:15 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-09-02 12:00:20 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-09-02 12:00:25 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-09-02 12:00:30 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-09-02 12:00:35 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-09-02 12:00:40 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-09-02 12:00:45 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

**So the query need to count rising edge only for each column, grouped by date on time column.**

Expected result :

| date | def1 | def2 | def3 | def4 | def5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 2022-09-02 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 1 |

I've got now about 30 columns and 3'800'000 records for 6 months of logs. Our customer wants to keep at least 6 months, ideally 2 years of logs.

So, for me the difficulties are to be efficient in storage but also to retrieve data as quick as possible.

### FINDING SOLUTION

Based on the following logical (n = actual record, m = previous record) :

```
m    0 0 1 1
n    0 1 0 1
     _______
x    0 1 0 0
```

We will get only rising edge (not falling edge) so change between 0 to 1 and ignore all other values :

```
Def3 on 2022-09-02              0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0
occurred 3 times                   ↑     ↑           ↑      

finding solution :
n - m                           0  1 -1  1  0 -1  0  1  0 -1   
ABS(n - m)                      0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  
n XOR m                         0  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1
```

*So, how to get only rising edges !? In other words, how to get only `1` values as `true` and `-1/0` as `false`*

Comment: *I've got now about 30 columns and 3'800'000 records for 6 months of logs. Our customer wants to keep at least 6 months, ideally 2 years of logs.* Store raw data. the table with 16kk rows of (datetime + 30 booleans) must be compact enough, less than 1 GByte.

Comment: Well, actually, this table contains a lot of other data (about 120 columns), like some VARCHAR, INTEGER, DECIMAL(5,2) and those default TINYINT we talk about here. Maybe I could split it into several tables. I'll think about it but When INSERT (ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE) I need to be faster as possible. So all in one table is maybe the faster.

Comment: *Maybe I could split it into several tables.* If normalizatoin does not need in this then this vertical sharding may be not safe, it can decrease the performance for your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS ( 
    SELECT DATE(dt) dt, def1, def2, def3, def4, def5, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(dt) ORDER BY dt) rn
    FROM test
)
SELECT dt,
       SUM(t2.def1 > t1.def1) def1,
       SUM(t2.def2 > t1.def2) def2,
       SUM(t2.def3 > t1.def3) def3,
       SUM(t2.def4 > t1.def4) def4,
       SUM(t2.def5 > t1.def5) def5
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2 USING (dt)
WHERE t2.rn = t1.rn + 1
GROUP BY 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8402e9ea53a0aa580b18868c913465a

Comment: Wow, love this. Thanks I learned something there :)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading I found solution :

`CAST(value AS BOOL/BOOLEAN)` is not available in MySQL, but `CAST(value > 0 AS UNSIGNED)` is the workaround.

Database records :

```
Def3 on 2022-09-02              0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0
we want 3 only rising edges        ↑     ↑           ↑
```

Finding rising edges :

```
CAST( (n - m) > 0 AS UNSIGNED)  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  
rising edge only 3 times           ↑     ↑           ↑
```

So, here is my solution to get defaults occurred every day, but I think it's not the best we can do :

```
SUM( CAST( (n - m) > 0 AS UNSIGNED) ) ... GROUP BY date(`time`) is now returning 3 as expected.
```

Complete query :

```
WITH `stats` AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        DATE(`time`)                    AS `date`,          
        (@pos := ifnull(@pos, 0) + 1)   AS `pos`

    FROM `def_log`
    #WHERE ... // your filters here
    ORDER BY `time` ASC
)

SELECT       
    SUM( CAST( (S2.`Def1` - S1.`Def1`) > 0 AS UNSIGNED) ) AS `Def1`, 
    SUM( CAST( (S2.`Def2` - S1.`Def2`) > 0 AS UNSIGNED) ) AS `Def2`, 
    SUM( CAST( (S2.`Def3` - S1.`Def3`) > 0 AS UNSIGNED) ) AS `Def3`, 
    SUM( CAST( (S2.`Def4` - S1.`Def4`) > 0 AS UNSIGNED) ) AS `Def4`, 
    SUM( CAST( (S2.`Def5` - S1.`Def5`) > 0 AS UNSIGNED) ) AS `Def5`
    
FROM `stats` S1
INNER JOIN `stats` S2 
    ON S1.`pos` = S2.`pos` - 1

GROUP BY S2.`date`;
```

Comment: Incorrect. Your CTE does not contain ORDER BY, so the rows processing order is not defined, and the output is non-deterministic. PS. What is the reason to emulate ROW_NUMBER() function? if CTE is available then this window function is available too.

Comment: You're right, my complete query with correct columns names contains filters (WHERE) for periods and ORDER BY too. Thanks, I'll fix it.

For ROW NUMBER it is because I don't have ID on table and doesn't know how to iterate previous record ! Actually I was thinking that use `time` column with < compare will be slower than @pos var.